# How to find frequency from graph after i solve equation by using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, frequency

How i can find a frequency from graph after i solve equation by using NDsolve. I try to find frequency, and after that i want to plot a graph frequency versus alpha.
This is my code

```
g = 1
w = 3                      (*frequency*)
y = 1                       (*nonlinearity*)
V0 = 5.74             (* external potential*)
q0 = 0.1              (*alpha*)
A0 = 1                    (* initial amplitude*)
d0 = -0.5             (* initial center-of-mass position*)
a0 = 1                    (* initial width*)
I1 = 2*V0*q0*a[t]*Sqrt[π]*d[t]           
I2 = 2*V0*q0*a[t]^3*d[t]*Sqrt[π]/2        
I3 = 2*V0*q0*a[t]^3*Sqrt[π]/2                     
Q1 = V0*a[t]^3*Sqrt[π]/2 + V0*a[t]*d[t]^2*Sqrt[π]                                    
Q2 = V0*a[t]^5*(3 Sqrt[π])/4 + V0*a[t]^3*d[t]^2*Sqrt[π]/2                             
F = Sqrt[π]/2*V0*A[t]^2*a[t]^3 + Sqrt[π]*V0*A[t]^2*a[t]*d[t]^2


s = NDSolve[{
A'[t] ==  A[t]*b[t] - (I2*A[t])/(Sqrt[π]*a[t]^3) + (3*A[t]*I1)/( 2*Sqrt[π]*a[t]),                  

k'[t] == (2*Sqrt[π]*V0*A[t]^2*a[t]*d[t])/(  Sqrt[π]*A[t]^2*a[t]) + (4*b[t]*I3)/( Sqrt[π]*a[t]),             

a'[t] == -2*a[t]*b[t] - I1/Sqrt[π] + (2*I2)/( Sqrt[π]*a[t]^2),               

d'[t] == -k[t] + (2*I3)/(Sqrt[π]*a[t]),           

b'[t] == -(1/(2*a[t]^4)) + 2*b[t]^2 + (y*A[t]^2)/( 2*Sqrt[2]*a[t]^2) + (g*A[t]^2*a[t])/( 2*Sqrt[2]*(a[t]^2 + w^2)^(3/2)) + (2*Q2)/(Sqrt[π]*a[t]^5) -      Q1/(Sqrt[π]*a[t]^3),                    

A[0] == 1, k[0] == 0.1, a[0] == 1, d[0] == -0.5, b[0] == 0}, {A, k,
a, d, b}, {t, 0, 50}]


  ysol[t_] := d[t] /. s[[1]]

 (*plot graph for center-of-mass position versus time*)
 Plot[ysol[t], {t, 0, 50}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {All, All}, 
 FrameLabel -> {StyleForm["time (s) ", FontSize -> 14], 
  StyleForm["ξ (center-of-mass position)", FontSize -> 14]}]
```

How i can find frequency from peak to peak? what code i should use.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127167/how-to-find-period-of-the-interpolating-function/127172#127172

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the frequencies using the FFT. Starting from your solution for `ysol`

[image]

```
ydis = Table[ysol[i], {i, 0, 50, 0.001}];
fft = Fourier[ydis, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
ListLinePlot[shortFFT = Abs[fft[[1 ;; 100]]], PlotRange -> All]
FindPeaks[shortFFT]
```

[image]

```
{{2, 164.085}, {28, 13097.5}, {57, 2696.74}}
```

The two major peaks represent the two major frequencies, which occur at FFT indices 28 and 57. Since the signal `ysol` was sampled at 1000 Hz (time intervals of 0.001 sec), these represent frequencies of 0.28 and 0.57 Hz. Perhaps this represents a periodic wave with two major harmonics.

Alternatively, one could directly look for the positions of the peaks in ysol.

```
ydis = Table[ysol[i], {i, 0, 50, 0.001}];
indPeaks = Differences[First@Transpose[FindPeaks[ydis]]];
dist = Mean[indPeaks] // N
1000/dist

1813.56
0.551403
```

Using this method, there are an average of 1813 samples between peaks, which is about 1.8 sec between peaks, for a frequency of about 0.55 Hz.

Comment: i want to ask for x and y axis, what it represent, respectively? and how to find the coordinate {28, 13097.5}, what code that i must use to show that coordinate?

Comment: The code is just above the output in each case. Thus `FindPeaks[shortFFT]` gives the {28, 13097.5}.