# What is the syntax for using Reap and Sow and WhenEvent with derivative = 0 with interpolating function?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, interpolation, frequency

I have a system of three ODEs. This system oscillates. I need to determine the frequency of each of the three solutions.

[My file. You can download and modify this.](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/1c1d9200-f4a3-44fd-a39e-e68bfb8d74b5)

I'm new to Mathematica and I know this question has been asked multiple times, but I can't get it working.

```
{xSol, ySol, zSol} = NDSolveValue[{ode1, ode2, ode3, ic2}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 200}]
```

Plotting `xSol`, `ySol` and `zSol` (three interpolating functions) gives:

[image: Solutions]

Can anyone show me how to determine the frequency of this thing using [`Reap` and `Sow`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127167/how-to-find-period-of-the-interpolating-function/127172#127172) *or* [FFT](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127172/72892). I've been instructed already how to do this using EcoEvo package, but I'm also wondering how to do it without such a package.

Both the [Reap/Sow solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127167/how-to-find-period-of-the-interpolating-function/127172#127172) and the [FFT](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127172/72892) come pretty close to what I have and need. But I fail in modifying the mentioned solutions so that it works with my code.

How do I individually determine the frequency of `xSol`, `ySol` and `zSol`?

---

**My implementation of WhenEvent**

For example, when I try to use `WhenEvent`, I used it like this:

```
{xSol, ySol, zSol} = NDSolveValue[{ode1, ode2, ode3, ic2, WhenEvent[x'[t] == 0, Sow[t]]}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 200}]
```

This gives me an error (which I presume to be about the WhenEvent) and my regular solutions. Because the solutions *are* correct, I think that the problem here is in the WhenEvent.

[image: Errors]

Error: Event location failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations between t = ... and t = ....

**LATER UPDATE**

```
{{xSol, ySol, zSol}, reapresult} = Reap[NDSolveValue[{ode1, ode2, ode3, ic2, WhenEvent[x[t] > .4 && x'[t] == 0,Sow[t]]}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 200} ]]
```

This outputs and empty list `{}`

I first forgot to add the `Reap[]`

All suggestions and solutions are highly appreciated! Many thanks

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful if you explained exactly *how* you are failing to adapt the solution you linked to.

Comment: Yes of course, thanks Natas!

Comment: OK, I think this has to do with the fact that `x` is (almost) zero for a long time. You can use (for instance) the condition `x[t] == .8 && x'[t] > 0` instead, although this of course has to be modified for similar problems. I suggest you have a look at the documentation of `WhenEvent`.

Comment: You can look at my source code at (https://github.com/cklausme/EcoEvo/blob/master/EcoEvo/EcoEvo.nb) for inspiration.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks ;-) but as a Mathematica novice it's still one level too high

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. My initial code

```
{{xSol, ySol, zSol}, reapresult} = Reap[NDSolveValue[{ode1, ode2, ode3, ic2, WhenEvent[x[t] > .4 && x'[t] == 0,Sow[t]]}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 200} ]]
```

gives an empty list for reapresult. But when I switch the order in the `WhenEvent`, it *does* give me the correct list.

```
{{xSol, ySol, zSol}, reapresult} = Reap[NDSolveValue[{ode1, ode2, ode3, ic2, WhenEvent[x'[t] == 0 && x[t] > 0.1,Sow[t]]}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 200} ]]
```

Thanks everyone for thinking along!

Comment: See [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39374/inconsistent-behavior-of-whenevent) for more info on this point.